# Escaping a character in HTML value param

Tags: html, jelly

I have a `TextArea` in my jelly file. I would like to have something like
`'${JOB_NAME}`' for its value. But when I do that it checks for the environment variable "`JOB_NAME"`. I just want to escape `${` and `}` so that it will display it as it is without trying to interpret it.

```
<f:textarea name = "script"  value = "${JOB_NAME}">
```

How would I do that?

Comment: as-have-mentioned-above? Why don't you make your example actually say `${JOB_NAME}`

Comment: just some notes - HTML text area does not have attribute value, HTML does not interpret ${ values. So it is your template engine, which one? what is written in documentation about escaping?

Comment: @Lashane Sounds like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/tutorial.html

Comment: I have never heard of jelly but you should try `$${JOB_NAME}`,

Comment: @JuanMendes $${JOB_NAME} worked. Please answer so that I could accept the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$${JOB_NAME}` to prevent `$` from being interpolated.

See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/faq.html#escapingJexl